# Android, images and dpi

Tags: android, resolution, dpi

I am using WVGA800 skin in Android emulator, so the density (hw.lcd.density) is 240. I have to put 4 image buttons (72 pixels per inch) at the bottom of activities view. As the resolution is 480X800, I asummed that the width of image must be 120 pixels. The problem is when application is launched,  the 3 buttons take all width  and there is no place for 4th button... Then I created button image in Fireworks with resolution 240 pixels per inch and in 120px width, but problem remains. Could somebody explain how to make correct drawables (sizes and dpi) so that they can be displayed pixel in pixel on Android?

Answer (score 5):

If you put your images in `res/drawable`, Android assumes they're for 160dpi and scales them accordingly for different resolutions.

Your options are either to put the button images into `res/drawable-hdpi` signaling that they're intended for densities around 240dpi, or into `res/drawable-nodpi` to make them never scale regardless of the current screen density.

You still reference them as `@drawable/whatever` in layouts, the engine picks the best match automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the image DPI entirely. It's irrelevant, all you need to know is the pixel size. What I would actually suggest is to create a [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) image to use as your button background. You'll actually need a few to put into a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), as this is how the different focus states are defined (e.g. Pressed, Focused). Once you have your NinePatch, just create a LinearLayout like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_nine_patch"
        android:text="button 1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_nine_patch"
        android:text="button 2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_nine_patch"
        android:text="button 3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/my_nine_patch"
        android:text="button 4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Set all the buttons to `fill_parent` and give them all an equal weight. They'll stretch to fit evenly to the parent, and you don't have to worry at all about specifying a constant pixel or dip size. Also, it'll evenly split onto any Android device, no matter the resolution.

Comment: 1) As I understand WVGA800 resolution is 800X480 (height x width). And this resolution also is metioned in HTC Desire specification (my testing env). 480 diveded by 4 is 120, so the each button must be 120 pixels wide. How 480 can be 320 (if so, then really in my case there is no space for 4th button)? 
2) I am trying to avoid "stretching" as my images contains gradients and after the streching they look blury; so insted of "stretching" I want to achieve perfect pixel in pixel at least for one my prefered resolution.
Can somebody provide more information on this subject?

Comment: The 320 pixel comment was not mine. In theory your buttons should be 120 pixels, but keep in mind the padding between them as well, plus, what happens when the user rotates into landscape orientation? You can handle gradients with 9-patch images, it's just a little trickier. Here's some more information on 9-patches: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=580351

Answer (score 0):

The width is actually 320 pixels, so for 4 buttons across the entire screen set each to 80dip. Android will then adjust your density independent pixels to the proper screen size of 480 pixels.

Comment: As I wrote if 800X480 device is used with layout where are 4 buttons (ImageButton with resources in 72 pixels/cm, standard resolution in Fireworks CS5 and I also believe in Photoshop) each 120px in width. If px is replaced with dp, then there was no space for my 4th button and all buttons were stretched and blurry. There is only one explanation 1px IS NOT 1dp!!! So to use dp, you have to divide px with 1.5. For example, if my image is 60px, I have to use 40dp in layout. This approach works also in lower resolution devices, for example HTC wildfire - my ImageButtons were resized correctly.